# HTML 5 Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html

StackOverflow,

I'm a NOOB learning slowly.  I got some errors  when trying to validate the following code in HTML 5 validator and don't know where the errors are:

```
    <!DoctypeHTML>
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <title> Javascript Programming!</title>
    <script type = “text/javascript”>
    <function substitute () {
    var  MyValue = document.getElementID (‘mytextbox’).value;
    If (myValue ==0) {
    alert(‘please enter a real value in the box’);
    Return;
    }
    Var myTitle = document.getElementbyID (‘title’)
    myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
    }
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Errors:  Error: Bad value “text/javascript” for attribute type on element script: Expected a token character but saw “ instead.
From line 5, column 2; to line 5, column 34
↩   ↩

Error: End of file seen when expecting text or an end tag.
At line 18, column 7
dy>↩

Error: Unclosed element script.
From line 5, column 2; to line 5, column 34
↩   ↩

Any feedback?  Thanks guys and gals.

PreYvin

Comment: Remove `<` from `<function`. Also `If` `Return` & `Var` will be in lowercase

Comment: http://validator.w3.org

Comment: (1) You are not closing your `<script>` tag. (2) Remove `<` from `<function` (3) Use regular quotes instead of typographical

Comment: Looks like you are trying to write code in Microsoft Word...

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa And, correct all the case-sensitive errors.

Comment: @Johannes


Thank you for the feedback.  Awesome info.  Yeah, I'm using a basic text editor.  I tried to write the code down on a napkin, transfer it to the text editor and then run the validator.  So many errors for some tiny problems.  
Thank you guys.  I look forward to sharing.  This is awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have invalid JavaScript so this should be valid.

```
<!doctype html>
<HTML>
<head>
<title> Javascript Programming!</title>
<script>
function substitute () {
var  MyValue = document.getElementID (‘mytextbox’).value;
if (myValue ==0) {
alert(‘please enter a real value in the box’);
return;
}
var myTitle = document.getElementbyID (‘title’)
myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using typographical quotes - change these to regular quotes. (single and double)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you've got a whole lot of invalid code (HTML and JavaScript) here:

```
<!DoctypeHTML>
```

Should be (case doesn't matter):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This:

```
<script type = “text/javascript”>
```

contains typographically formatted quotes instead of non-formatted quotes, which is a problem, but you don't even need the `type=text/javascript` anyway, so you can just write:

```
<script>
```

`function` is not an HTML tag, so this:

```
<function substitute () {
```

should be:

```
function substitute() {
```

Next, you are using formatted quotes in your JavaScript:

```
var  MyValue = document.getElementID (‘mytextbox’).value;
```

which should be unformatted, like this:

```
var  MyValue = document.getElementID ('mytextbox').value;
```

HTML isn't case-sensitive, but JavaScript is, so this:

```
If (myValue ==0) {
```

needs to be this:

```
if (myValue == 0)
```

More quote problems here:

```
alert(‘please enter a real value in the box’);
```

Should be:

```
alert('please enter a real value in the box');
```

More case-sensitivity issues here:

```
Return;
```

Should be:

```
return;
```

More quote and case-sensitivity issues here:

```
Var myTitle = document.getElementbyID (‘title’)
```

Should be:

```
var myTitle = document.getElementbyID ('title');
```

Lastly, when your script is finished and it's time to return to HTML, you didn't close your script, so this:

```
}
</head>
```

Should be:

```
}
</script>
</head>
```

- You can always validate your HTML at: http://validator.w3.org
- And, you can validate your JavaScript at: http://www.jslint.com

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Awesome info.  Yeah, I'm using a basic text editor.  I tried to write the code down on a napkin, transfer it to the text editor and then run the validator.  So many errors for some tiny problems.  
Thank you guys.  I look forward to sharing.  This is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

you have an extra < in your code. but you need to revisit your javascript as it has many problems the script tag is not closed.

```
   <!DoctypeHTML>
        <HTML>
        <head>
        <title> Javascript Programming!</title>
        <script type = “text/javascript”>
       function substitute () {
        var  MyValue = document.getElementID (‘mytextbox’).value;
        If (myValue ==0) {
        alert(‘please enter a real value in the box’);
        Return;
        }
        Var myTitle = document.getElementbyID (‘title’)
        myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
        }
</script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Awesome info.  Yeah, I'm using a basic text editor.  I tried to write the code down on a napkin, transfer it to the text editor and then run the validator.  So many errors for some tiny problems.  
Thank you guys.  I look forward to sharing.  This is awesome.

Comment: @PreYvin don't forget to choose an answer to your post so this can get valid.

Comment: @KhaledQuertani 
How do I choose the answer to get it validated?

Comment: @PreYvin To accept an answer:

Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.
Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive. Wait until you receive an answer that answers your question well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close your `<script>` tag.
2. Remove `<` from `<function`
3. Use regular quotes instead of typographical
4. space between `Doctype` and `html` ie. `<!doctype html>`
5. Lastly, keywords should be all smallcase ie. `if`, `return`, `var`

Updated

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Javascript Programming!</title>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
function substitute () {
var  MyValue = document.getElementID ('mytextbox').value;
if (myValue == 0) {
alert('please enter a real value in the box');
return;
}
var myTitle = document.getElementbyID ('title')
myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
}
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Awesome info.  Yeah, I'm using a basic text editor.  I tried to write the code down on a napkin, transfer it to the text editor and then run the validator.  So many errors for some tiny problems.  
Thank you guys.  I look forward to sharing.  This is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of basic syntax errors here.

- `<!DoctypeHTML>` should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- the first error you listed, (Bad value “text/javascript” for attribute type on element script: Expected a token character but saw “ instead.) is due to a funky double quote character: “ It should be " This probably originated from your text editor. What are you using? I like Sublime, but there are lots of options. The important thing is that you use a text editor designed for coding.
- the next two errors are due to your script tag not being closed. Just add `</script>` at the end of the script.

Like I said, these are just simple syntax errors though. What you really need to learn here is how to look at those error messages and tell what's going on. Notice how the error messages reference a line number and column number? That's to tell you where the problem is. (Sometimes it can be off depending on the error, but worry about that later). Take a look at the line it's complaining about, read the error message, and you should be able to figure out what's wrong.